# how to get image on my javascript without putting it in HTML

Tags: javascript, image

I'm trying to create a blackjack game and although I'm struggling with Javascript, I'm trying to store images inside of an image folder so I once I get the random deal, it pops out to be a spade, club, diamond, or heart. Do I store this in my array of cards ? I basically have an array of objects for every card in the deck. Any suggestions?

Comment: put the image path in your card object?

Comment: can you help me out with that? storing the images in my image folder in sublime text and then implement it in my object?

Comment: what @Travis J said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to do here is take an approach called preloading.

Basically, you have a folder or set of images that can be used as cards. Hopefully they are named in a way which makes them easy to iterate.

You are going to want to create a new image object and once that image has its src set to a value, the path to your image, it will load it, even though it is not being rendered to the screen.

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = "/imgs/cards/Spades/1.gif";//Load the Ace
```

This would allow you to basically create the whole set if they were in numbers

```
var spades = [];
for(var i = 1; i < 14; i++){
    var spade = new Image();
    spade.src = "/imgs/cards/Spades/"+i+".gif";
}
```

Now if you need to show one of these cards simply create an html image element, and set its source to the source of the image object in your spades array.

```
var card = document.createElement("img");
card.src = spades[0].src;//ace
document.body.appendChild(card);//will show the ace
```

This is just a simple example of getting it on the screen, but it will obviously take a lot more work to incorporate preloading into your exact scenario. However, taking this approach will allow the card to show instantly as it has been preloaded (cached) already.